# React Material-ui library Error Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `active`. while using Stepper component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I recently tried upgrading from material-ui v 0.x to material-ui v3.9.3 and facing a strange compile time error for Stepper Component

The code is working perfectly fine in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8zqtj) however the same code is giving strange error (See the screenshot). However I removed all other complexities of my code and tried putting simple stepper, the issue is still the same

here is my code

```
<Stepper activeStep={stepIndex}>
   <Step
     active={true}
   >
      <StepButton
        icon={(<FavoriteIcon />)}
             onClick={() => {}}
      >
         <StepLabel>step1</StepLabel>
      </StepButton>
   </Step>
   <Step active={false}>
     <StepButton
       icon={(<FavoriteIcon />)}
             onClick={() => {}}
     >
        <StepLabel>step2</StepLabel>
          </StepButton>
     </Step>
     <Step>
       <StepButton
         icon={(<FavoriteIcon />)}
              onClick={() => {}}
       >
          <StepLabel>step3</StepLabel>
       </StepButton>
     </Step>
   </Stepper>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You will have to pass true as a string in your code for the prop active in Stepper component. as of now, you are passing a boolean value. So you have to use the code below

```js
<Stepper activeStep={stepIndex}>
   <Step
     active={"true"}
   >
      <StepButton
        icon={(<FavoriteIcon />)}
             onClick={() => {}}
      >
         <StepLabel>step1</StepLabel>
      </StepButton>
   </Step>
   <Step active={"false"}>
     <StepButton
       icon={(<FavoriteIcon />)}
             onClick={() => {}}
     >
        <StepLabel>step2</StepLabel>
          </StepButton>
     </Step>
     <Step>
       <StepButton
         icon={(<FavoriteIcon />)}
              onClick={() => {}}
       >
          <StepLabel>step3</StepLabel>
       </StepButton>
     </Step>
   </Stepper>
```

Comment: that is wrong , see the documentation https://material-ui.com/api/step/ , howeever even if I pass string its not working. it will show different error -> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `active` of type `string` supplied to `Step`, expected `boolean`

Comment: You should check the link you have provided above in your question of code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8zqtj), It is passing the value as a string. How it is wrong ?

Comment: you are right, and I was wrong in that case, I was just trying with different possibilities hence forgot to remove double quotes. however its not working fine even with string value.